# Have a lifecycle hook trigger an EC2 Run Command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lifecycle, autoscaling

Can I have an auto scaling lifecycle hook trigger an EC2 Run Command that starts a scheduled task on a windows instance?

I've only see them used to trigger lamdas. It would be nice if I could kick off a Run Command that runs a local script on an instance when the auto scaled instance is terminating- or I should say before it terminates.

Comment: What do you want to achieve here?